# kdb/Q How to renumber rows in table?

Tags: kdb

If I have a table like the one below:

| Iteration | Score |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 87 |
| 3 | 10 |

I reordered by Score descending:

`` ordered: `Score desc first_table; ``

| Iteration | Score |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 87 |
| 1 | 20 |
| 3 | 10 |

How can I then renumber the Iteration column, so the output is something like below? I am thinking of creating a new column that gets the index # of every row, then replacing the original Iteration column.

| Iteration | Score |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 87 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 10 |

Comment: You can probably do something like `select iteration:i+1, desc score from table`. This makes use of the virtual column i. See: https://code.kx.com/q/basics/qsql/#virtual-column-i

Comment: Great thank you, it looks like I can also sort the Iteration column as well (re rianoc's answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the columns not the table:

```
update asc Iteration, desc Score from tab
```

Comment: That worked, thanks for letting me know about this!

Answer (score 1):

Given that your table in practice likely has many more columns, you could also regenerate the index column after an `xdesc`

```
q)update iteration:i+1 from `score xdesc([]iteration:1+til 3;score:20 87 10;col1:3?`3;col2:3?10.0)
iteration score col1 col2
-----------------------------
1         87    enf  5.347096
2         20    fgl  7.85033
3         10    plh  7.111716
```